# Swift Generic "Numeric" Protocol that Validates Numeric Values

Tags: swift, protocols

Swift 3.

Ultimately my functions need to receive `UInt8` data types, but I'm never sure if the arguments I will receive from callers will be `Int`, `Int64`, `UInt`, `Float`, etc. I know they will be **numeric** types, I just don't know which flavor.

I could do:

```
func foo(value: Int) { }
func foo(value: Float) {}
func foo(value: UInt) {}
```

But that's crazy. So I thought I could do something like create a protocol

```
protocol ValidEncodable {
}
```

And then pass in types that conform:

```
func foo(value: ValidEncodable) { }
```

And then in that function I could get my values into the correct format

```
func foo(value: ValidEncoable) -> UInt8 {
    let correctedValue = min(max(floor(value), 0), 100)
    return UInt8(correctedValue)
}
```

I'm really struggling to figure out

1) How to create this ValidEncodable protocol that contains all the *numeric* types

2) And how to do things like floor(value) when the value I get is an Int without iterating over every possible numeric type (i.e. (floor(x) is only available on floating-point types)

Ultimately I need the values to be UInt8 in the range of 0-100. The whole reason for this madness is that I'm parsing XML files to my own internal data structures and I want to bake in some validation to my values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without a protocol, and by making use of compiler checks, which greatly reduces the changes of bugs.

My recommendation is to use a partial function - i.e. a function that instead of taking an int, it takes an already validated value. Check [this article](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/01/25/partial-functions-part-one-avoidance.html) for a more in-depth description of why partial functions are great.

You can build a Int0to100 struct, which has either a failable or throwable initializer (depending on taste):

```
struct Int0to100 {
    let value: UInt8

    init?(_ anInt: Int) {
        guard anInt >= 0 && anInt <= 100 else { return nil }
        value = UInt8(anInt)
    }

    init?(_ aFloat: Float) {
        let flooredValue = floor(aFloat)
        guard flooredValue >= 0 && flooredValue <= 100 else { return nil }
        value = UInt8(flooredValue)
    }

    // ... another initializers can be added the same way
}
```

and change `foo` to allow to be called with this argument instead:

```
func foo(value: Int0to100) {
    // do your stuff here, you know for sure, at compile time,
    // that the function can be called with a valid value only
}
```

You move to the caller the responsibility of validating the integer value, however the validation resolves to checking an optional, which is easy, and allows you to handle the scenario of an invalid number with minimal effort.

Another important aspect is that you explicitly declare the domain of the `foo` function, which improves the overall design of the code.

And not last, enforcements set at compile time greatly reduce the potential of having runtime issues.

Comment: Great article! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* your incoming values will lie in 0..<256, then you can just construct a `UInt8` and pass it to the function.

```
func foo(value: UInt8) -> UInt8 { return value }
let number = arbitraryNumber()
print(foo(UInt8(number)))
```

This will throw a runtime exception if the value is too large to fit in a byte, but otherwise will work. You could protect against this type of error by doing some bounds checking between the second and third lines.

Comment: Thanks! This is one the problems. I don't know the value I will be receiving. Sometimes I get -256, sometimes I get 10.5. I have to always check for overflows. Maybe I could rewrite as

Comment: That's why I said you could add bounds checking between the second and third lines. You could do something (use a default value, exit early) if `number` doesn't lie in `0...100`.